# mod_rewrite redirecting css/js requests in HTML as well

Tags: mod-rewrite

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^((app_.*?)|models|plugins|jig) - [F,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Above is my .htaccess file... and index.php is logging each request. When I check my logs, I get the first expected rewrite logged, and then I get rewrite logs for every JS/CSS inclusion in the HTML output from the first rewrite.

The CSS/JS paths in the markup are valid direct paths to files that exist, so it seems that it should never get to my `RewriteRule` above. Anyone experience a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try it the other way:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```